# how do i insert value into a column and referring the previous value at the same time of that column in a Table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where I have to insert values in Final_value column

```
date      column1  column2   Final_value   
01-01-10    5.5       Null        Null
02-01-10    4.2       Null        NULL
03-01-10    5.3       0.4         NULL
04-01-10    6.4       Null        NULL
05-01-10    7.0       0.3         NULL
06-01-10    7.7       Null        NULL
```

**Explanation of the task**

1. First value of the Final_value column will be = 1st value of column1 i.e 5.5
2. From the 2nd row we will check if column2 is **Not Null**
   a) if TRUE , then formula would be
   previous Final_value column* ( current column1 value/previous Column1 value ) + column2
   value * (previous column1 value/ previous Final_value )

   b) if FALSE, then formula would be
   the Previous value of Final_value column * ( current value of column1/ previous
   value of column 1)

**Required Output**

```
date      column1  column2   Final_value   
01-01-10    5.5       Null        5.5
02-01-10    4.2       Null        4.2
03-01-10    5.3       0.4         5.7
04-01-10    6.4       Null        6.883019
05-01-10    7.0       0.3         7.850943
06-01-10    7.7       Null        8.636038
```

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: The problem is you don't have any unique value (like Id).  You can't use date-1 because what might happen if there is no data on a specific date. But you can use a procedure to update it.

Comment: I am stuck as I am not able to refer to the previous value of Final_value column while updating it. And for getting the previous value of column1 I used the lag function and created a new column @RobertoHernandez

Comment: is the column date NOT NULL always ?

Comment: Can we use Rownum() to create a unique row no,  will that be helpful? @Rezu

Comment: yes @RobertoHernandez

Comment: @Amit, Final value is a existing column or a calculated column ?

Comment: Please, describe what should be the result if previous value of `column2` is null? Because for the second row you get `4.2`, but the formula should return `null`. I cannot get `5.7` for the third row also.

Comment: I am really sorry it should have been column 1. I have corrected the question @Rezu

Comment: Third `final_value` should be `4.2 * (4.2 / 5.3) + .4 (4.2 / 4.2)` which gives `3.72`  - **other value** that in your sample output??

Comment: Corrected the formula it should be 4.2 * (5.3/4.2) + .4 (4.2 / 4.2) @MarmiteBomber Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Updated the answer, not the result is as expected!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare
v_num integer := 1;
v_column1 number(8,2);
v_column2 number(8,2);
v_Final_value number(8,2);
begin
for rec in (select * from tab order by mydate)
loop
   if(v_num = 1) then
       
       update tab set Final_value = column1 where mydate = rec.mydate;     
   else
       if(rec.column2 is not null) then
          update tab set Final_value =
           v_Final_value * (v_column1/rec.column1) +
           rec.column2 * (v_column1/v_Final_value) where mydate = rec.mydate;
       else
          update tab set Final_value =
          v_Final_value * (rec.column1 / v_column1) where mydate = rec.mydate;
       end if;
   end if;
   
   
   v_num:= v_num +1;
   
   v_column1 := rec.column1;
   v_column2 := rec.column2;
   
   select final_value 
   into v_Final_value
   from tab
   where mydate = rec.mydate;
     
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Row-by-row update is not very good approach. It may be better to `bulk collect` updated rows and then perform single update with [`forall`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/FORALL-statement.html#GUID-C45B8241-F9DF-4C93-8577-C840A25963DB) which is a way much faster. You need only current and one previous row for each calculation, which may be handled without access to the previously calculated stored values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your table contains consecutive days and you start with the smalest one, you can use a recursive subquery factoring to get your expected data.

```
with t1(date_d, column1, column2, Final_value) as (
 select date_d, column1, column2, column1 Final_value 
 from tab 
 where date_d = (select min(date_d) from tab)
union all
 select t2.date_d, t2.column1, t2.column2, 
 case when t2.column2 is not null then 
     t1.Final_value * (t2.column1 / t1.column1) + t2.column2 * (t1.column1 / t1.Final_value)
 else
     t1.Final_value * (t2.column1 / t1.column1)
 end as  Final_value 
 from t1
 join tab t2 on t1.date_d + 1 = t2.date_d
)
select * from t1
```

Note that the *anchor* subquery selects the first row with the minimal date and the initial `Final_value`

The recursive subquery (the second query in the `union all`) joins the row with the *next day*, so you can clearly describe your formula where `t1` reference the *previous* day and the `t2` the *current* one.

Result is as expected

```
DATE_D                 COLUMN1    COLUMN2 FINAL_VALUE
------------------- ---------- ---------- -----------
01.01.2010 00:00:00        5,5                    5,5
02.01.2010 00:00:00        4,2                    4,2
03.01.2010 00:00:00        5,3 ,4                 5,7
04.01.2010 00:00:00        6,4             6,88301887
05.01.2010 00:00:00          7 ,3          7,80724926
06.01.2010 00:00:00        7,7             8,58797418
```

Use it in `UPDATE/INSERT` as you like, but you may find that defining the `final_value` in a `view` only is the best solution...

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to use [`model`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) clause that allows straightforward reference to the previous calculation of the same measure without explicit recursion (and sometimes performs faster than recursive query). In the query below`cv()` is the current value of a dimension (i.e. `some_measure[cv() - 1]` is the value of column `measure` of the previous row). I've also added `nvl` to handle division by zero, which can be removed if you wish.

> ```
> with  b as (
>   select
>     a.*,
>     /*Add result column and auxiliarry numbering column to reference prevoius row*/
>     cast(null as number) as final_value,
>     row_number() over(order by dt asc) as rn
>   from a
> )
> select *
> from b
> model
>   /*Our generated ordering column*/
>   dimension by (rn)
>   /*Output columns apart from dimensions*/
>   measures (dt, column1, column2, final_value)
>   /*Ordered execution of the rules*/
>   rules update sequential order (
>     /*First row should have column1 value*/
>     final_value[1]= column1[cv()],
>     /*Other rows should have values according to formula*/
>     final_value[rn > 1] order by rn asc =
>       case
>         when column2[cv()] is not null
>         then final_value[cv() - 1]*column1[cv()]/nullif(column1[cv() - 1], 0)
>           + column2[cv()]*column1[cv() - 1]/nullif(final_value[cv() - 1], 0)
>         else
>           final_value[cv() - 1]*column1[cv()]/nullif(column1[cv() - 1], 0)
>       end
>   )
> ```

> ```
> RN | DT        | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |                              FINAL_VALUE
> -: | :-------- | ------: | ------: | ---------------------------------------:
>  1 | 01-JAN-10 |     5.5 |    null |                                      5.5
>  2 | 02-JAN-10 |     4.2 |    null |                                      4.2
>  3 | 03-JAN-10 |     5.3 |      .4 |                                      5.7
>  4 | 04-JAN-10 |     6.4 |    null | 6.88301886792452830188679245283018867925
>  5 | 05-JAN-10 |       7 |      .3 | 7.80724925521350546176762661370407149951
>  6 | 06-JAN-10 |     7.7 |    null | 8.58797418073485600794438927507447864946
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8022eaca994862801b28f7ccc5efb3b1)*

Comment: It's working really fine, but can we update multiple columns with this code? Like if I have Final_value_1 and Final_value_2

Comment: @Amit Of course, you can update any column that is not part of `dimension by` and `order by` parts of the `model` clause. Just put them in `rules`. The only prerequisite is to have that column in input data. However, you may add any number of columns of any type upfront with subquery (as I did in my example)